# How to make different development and production declaration of my rails engine in a gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile

I made an engine and try to use it in a project.
I would like to use the packaged engine on production and link to the project sources on development.

I add the following lines into the project's Gemfile.

```
gem 'mygem', '0.0.2', group: :production
gem 'mygem', '0.0.2', :path => '../mygemproject',  group: [:development, :test]
```

As a result, I've got an error 'You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources.'.

Is there a different way to do what I want ?

**Edit**

I read that Bundle don't know about Rails environment so I try this

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mygem',  '0.0.2', :path => '../mygemproject'
end

group :production do
 gem 'mygem',  '0.0.2'
end
```

Then I execute Bundle with the 'without' argument, I'd rather not doing that but I try

```
 bundle install --without production
```

Even like this I still have the 'cannot specify same gem twice' error.

Answer (score 2):

Just add your gem outside of the group so that it will be available in your development, test or production.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'mygem', '0.0.2'

group :development, :test do
end

group :test do
end

group :production do
end
```

Comment: Doing that my parent project will not be able to found my engine sources on development mode.

Comment: Try adding your `gem 'mygem', '0.0.2', path: '../mygemproject'` inside of the development and test group.